# CW Tags: need for them?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28463/8183), the question of having a CW tag so that community wikis can easily be browsed through cropped up. Could this be implemented?

Answer (score 5):

1. This would be a meta tag. Which are strongly discouraged across all sites of the network.
2. There is no need for a tag to begin with. Use the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://english.stackexchange.com/search):

   - [All CW questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion)
   - [All CW posts (questions and answers)](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1)
   - [Closed CW questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+closed%3A1+is%3Aquestion)
   - [CW questions tagged "meaning"](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion+%5Bmeaning%5D)
   - [All non-CW questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A0+is%3Aquestion)
   - etc.

Comment: +1 Ah! Great. [Silly dummy text as a filler, full of nothingness and nullity.]

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, that tag would be considered a meta tag; even in the case it would be considered a meta tag, it would still be a bad tag. A tag describes what is the topic of a question:

- [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) marks the question as being about the etymology of a phrase
- [adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjectives) is for questions related to adjectives
- [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) is for questions related to the meaning of a phrase

If I would see a question tagged [cw](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cw), I would get it's a question about Community Wikis, which would not be on-topic on EL&U.

Answer (score -1):

That's just what I was looking for! I was sure there was such a tag when I was going to browse all wikis on the website, but then it turned out there wasn't. I say we make such a tag. It would be a bit of work, though, to do it by hand, though we could get started with that if our Overlords haven't the time to implement this ...